# statistics - multivariate normal distn, variance and probability of event?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I have a multivariate Normal distribution defined by: μx = 360, μy = 280, μz = 180, σx = 40, σy = 34, σz = 48, and correlations of ρxy = −0.41, ρxz = −0.34, and ρyz = 0.47. I am required to find Variance(x+y+z). I don't know the formula for this - I can just guess that it's 40^2 + 34^2 + 48^2 +3*40*34*48*−0.41*−0.34*0.47, based on variance for bivariate. Is that right?

I am also asked to find P(z>150|x=350 and y=250). Does anyone know an equation that I could reference for this? I am given nothing in my textbook.

Comment: No, your formula for $\operatorname{var}(X+Y+Z)$ is incorrect.  Your textbook should be listing the correct formula (usually for $n$ variables) and you can specialize it to the case $n=3$. In any case, multiplying two correlation coefficients as in $-0.34\times 0.47$ is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

No,

$$V(X+Y+Z)=VX+VY+VZ + 2Cov(X,Y)+2Cov(X,Z)+2Cov(Y,Z).$$

This follows from the fact that if $X,Y,Z$ are mean zero variables then

$$V(X+Y+Z) = E(X+Y+Z)^2 = E(X^2+Y^2+Z^2+2XY+2XZ+2YZ).$$

If the mean is nonzero then the last displayed equality can be used noting that

$$V(X+Y+Z) = V(X-\mu_X + Y-\mu_Y+ Z-\mu_Z).$$

By the way, none of this has anything to do with the normal distribution.  This relationship holds for any distribution with finite second moments.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the equation on multivariate variance. Does anyone have an answer for the second part of my question, ie probability of event given a value of x and y?

Comment: You do need the normal for that.  Use the fact that $Z$ given $X=x,Y=y$ has a normal distribution with mean and variance given in the wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution among many other places.